# Finding xy-coordinates inside a polygon, which are the closest to the centroid of that specific polygon

Tags: raster, r

I have the following problem:

I have zip code regions, which basically have one single value attached to them most of the time. Then I have a grid consisting of grid boxes, which you can put over these zip code regions of interest.

What I want is the following: For every zip code region of interest, I want to attach the value from the zip code region to the grid coordinate, which is the closest to the centroid (see first figure below) of that zip code region. **That grid box must be inside of that zip code region**. It's enough actually, when I know which grid box in the zip code area is actually the closest one to the centroid of the zip code region. I can use these coordinates to index the grid boxes of relevance to me from the pixels plotted in figure 2 (see figure 2, where I didnt select the grid boxes closest to the centroids of a zip code region [figure 1]).

[image]

```
trueCentroids.zip_code_regions <- gCentroid(SpatialPolyDf.zip_code, byid=TRUE)  % Gives me the centroids of my zip code regions
```

Initially, I didnt care and just gave every grid box, which was inside of a specific zip code region the value, which is attached to this region (In the case a value existed for a specific region). The following figure and code should make that clearer:

```
> class(Spatialpixels_grid)
[1] "SpatialPixels"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

`Spatialpixels_grid` basically just contains coordinates, which I attach values to from the SpatialPolygonsDataframe object `SpatialPolyDf.zip_code` (see figure 2). For some regions, there are no values, so you see white pixels. The points represent the grid boxes, which are saved in `Spatialpixels_grid`.

```
Spatialpixels_grid$value_zip_code_region <- over(Spatialpixels_grid, SpatialPolyDf.zip_code)$value
```

[Example for using the function over](https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/point-in-polygon)

[image]

Is there the possibility to modify `over`, so I can achieve my goal?